# Are questions about regularization on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

My understanding is that physicists use regularization in aspects of quantum field theory.
indeed you will find regularization in EVERY book on quantum field theory (which in my understanding IS physics)

Am I not allowed to ask about regularization in physics SE? Why?

If regularization is not an acceptable physics SE question then please let me know and I'll stop trying to learn about it here

Comment: You've asked many questions on Meta all asking about nearly the same thing. Please stick to one question! Also, please tone down some of your past questions. It is a site on the computer after all, and while I can understand your frustration, there's no need to throw around insults. Please understand I'm not trying to insult you or anything, I just want to make sure you get an answer. People will be more likely to answer if you ask calmly and politely.

Comment: @heather thanks for your kind help.  Im not aware of insulting anyone and i felt my question, while connect, are distinct. There seem to be a handful of users targetting my posts and deleting and moving things claiming that regularization is not a physics topic or that it's an unclear topic.  Im trying to find out if we are allowed to ask questions about regularization   Anyways, thanks :p

Comment: yeah, no problem. I guess I'm just suggesting to think before you post, and combine related questions.

Comment: Thanks @heather, well said. I'd add that I think _this_ particular meta question is a very good one.

Comment: @DavidZ, definitely a good one.

Comment: The math part of the question is related to http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic i dont mean pure math...just regularization like one would encounter in physics

Comment: Just like how when physicists talk about quantum mechanics they usually mention vectors or hilbert spaces.  Or when people talk about E&M they might mention gauge invariance.  These are math things but math seems to be the language of physics.  It's probably not possible to learn physics without using mathematics

Comment: Perhaps a SE called "mathematical physics" would mke everyone happy.  That way physics SE could be only conceptual

Answer (score 3):

The subject of [regularization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularization) is on-topic if adequately put in a physics context. For some well-received examples of this, see e.g.

- [What is the relation between renormalization in physics and divergent series in mathematics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3096)
- [Regularization of the Casimir effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26877)
- [Regulator-scheme-independence in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57965)
- [Critical Dimension of Bosonic Strings and Regularization of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66371)
- [Why do we expect our theories to be independent of cutoffs?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73403)
- [What exactly is regularization in QFT?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92411)

Comment: So if i specifically say "im a physicist and therefor interested in regularization in QFT" then it becomes on topic?  I figured a priori regularization is on topic because regularization is a crucial aspect of QFT and it was being asked in a physics SE

Comment: I.e. ive always understood mathematical physics as being part of physics because usually physicists are not mathematicians

Comment: @user122066 I think the point of these questions is just that tone/context can make a question more or less well-received. It's possible your questions were closed because people didn't understand  how they related to physics. That's frustrating, but it's also your responsibility to write well-posed, focused questions.

Comment: @user122066 I'll also add that your infinite sum question in particular seemed to be answerable without any physics knowledge whatsoever, and thus BELONGED in the math stackexchange. It's not an insult to be moved to math if someone thinks you'll get better answers there.